# Postgresql SUM and UPDATE

Tags: postgresql

I want to ask about SUM and then UPDATE it in Postgresql DB. 
In my case I want to sum (units) in stockdiary table and then do the deduction/subtract with table products (stockvolume).  
 

I was able to sum the units in stockdiary table:

```
     SELECT NAME,SUM(UNITS) AS MINUS
     FROM STOCKDIARY
     INNER JOIN PRODUCTS
     ON PRODUCTS.ID = STOCKDIARY.PRODUCT
     GROUP BY NAME

     result =>
     name             ||    minus
     USB CABLE 1M     ||    -8  
     USB CHARGER      ||    -3
```

then the problem is how to subtract **minus** and **stockvolume** and update  it back to the products table?

stockdiary table 
 id(pk),datenew,product,units,price

products table 
 name,id(pk),pricebuy,pricesell,stockvolume

@Vivek.S thanks it works.

```
    UPDATE products
    SET stockvolume = sub.minus
    FROM (SELECT
    SUM(UNITS) AS MINUS,PRODUCTS.ID
    FROM STOCKDIARY
    INNER JOIN PRODUCTS ON PRODUCTS.ID = STOCKDIARY.PRODUCT
    GROUP BY NAME) sub
    WHERE sub.productid = products.productid
```

Comment: Please reformat to make it more readable.

Comment: @MattiasLindberg iam sorry please make me know if my question are not clear.

Comment: @Vivek.S i'll try.. thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 update  products  set stockvolume = stockvolume - diary.minus from 
(SELECT  STOCKDIARY.product,SUM(UNITS) AS MINUS
 FROM STOCKDIARY
 INNER JOIN PRODUCTS
 ON PRODUCTS.ID = STOCKDIARY.PRODUCT
 GROUP BY STOCKDIARY.product) as diary where products.id= diary.product
```

dont use reserved words as tablenames, column names and etc ... :)

Comment: its solve my proble .. but i must change "stockvolume + diary.minus) because my db already "-" for the stock volume..thank you